# How to get rid of the bogus choice generated by RadioSelect of Django Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using ModelForm on Django 1.3.

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
...
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('Unspecified', '')), default='M')
...
```

forms.py:

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('gender')
        widgets = {
            'gender': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

When this widget is rendered into HTML, I got

```
<ul> 
<li><label for="id_gender_0"><input type="radio" id="id_gender_0" value="" name="gender" />---------</label></li> 
<li><label for="id_gender_1"><input checked="checked" type="radio" id="id_gender_1" value="M" name="gender" /> Male</label></li> 
<li><label for="id_gender_2"><input type="radio" id="id_gender_2" value="F" name="gender" />Female</label></li> 
<li><label for="id_gender_3"><input type="radio" id="id_gender_3" value="" name="gender" /> Unspecified</label></li> 
</ul>
```

**Problem:** 
How can I get rid of the bogus choice "--------"?

The same problem was brought up by another stackoverflow user months ago ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248887/how-to-render-a-django-form-with-radioselect-without-getting-a-checked-radiobutto)). I have tried the accepted solution in there (as you can see) but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even without blank=True it shows the extra input. I have created a new Widget:

```
from itertools import chain
from django.forms import RadioSelect
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode

class RadioSelectNotNull(RadioSelect):
    def get_renderer(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        """Returns an instance of the renderer."""
        if value is None: value = ''
        str_value = force_unicode(value) # Normalize to string.
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)
        choices = list(chain(self.choices, choices))
        if choices[0][0] == '':
            choices.pop(0)
        return self.renderer(name, str_value, final_attrs, choices)
```

Comment: NickJ's answer appears to be correct, but I would like to add one thing. If I'm not mistaken, in the following line choices = list(chain(self.choices, choices)) chain requires an extra import: from itertools import chain

Comment: How to do it in django 1.11

Answer (score 6):

Set `blank=False` (or just remove it) and also add `default='Unspecified'`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the choices when you set the widget. It's showing the ---- because in your model you have blank=True.

Just use the choices arg of the widget and set it to the choices you set in your model.

Comment: This happens to me even when `blank=False` on the model.

Answer (score 1):

By default the  widget used by `ModelChoiceField` will have an empty choice at the top of the list.

You can change the text of this label (which is "---------" by default) with the empty_label attribute, or you can disable the empty label entirely by setting empty_label to None:

A custom empty label:

```
field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label="(Nothing)")
```

No empty label:

```
field2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Django <= 1.10**

RadioSelectNotNull widget

```
from itertools import chain
from django.forms import RadioSelect
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode

class RadioSelectNotNull(RadioSelect):
"""
A widget which removes the default '-----' option from RadioSelect
"""
    def get_renderer(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        """Returns an instance of the renderer."""
        if value is None: value = ''
        str_value = force_unicode(value) # Normalize to string.
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)
        choices = list(chain(self.choices, choices))
        if choices[0][0] == '':
            choices.pop(0)
        return self.renderer(name, str_value, final_attrs, choices)
```

**Django >= 1.11**

As after Django 1.10 following method is no more in RadioSelect or in its ancestors. That's why upper widget will not remove bogus choice generated by RadioSelect.

```
def get_renderer(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
```

So to remove bogus choice generated by RadioSelect use following widget. I have tested this till Django 2.0

```
from django.forms import RadioSelect
class RadioSelectNotNull(RadioSelect):
    """
    A widget which removes the default '-----' option from RadioSelect
    """
    def optgroups(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        """Return a list of optgroups for this widget."""
        if self.choices[0][0] == '':
            self.choices.pop(0)
        return super(RadioSelectNotNull, self).optgroups(name, value, attrs)
```