# How to remove "None" option in Django ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

For example, I have a model like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, _('type 1')),
        (2, _('type 2')),
    )
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

And for the form I have:

```
class ItemModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        widget = {
            'type': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

What I'd like to have is a radio select with 2 options ("type 1" and "type 2"). However, I will have 3 options, "---------", "type 1" and "type 2". The "---------" is for "None" I think, but the "type" field is required in the model, why does the "None" option still show up?

But if I use Form instead:

```
class ItemForm(forms.Form):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=Item.TYPE_CHOICES)
```

I will have only 2 options, "type 1" and "type 2", which is correct.

I'd like to use ModelForm over standard Form, but don't know how to remove the "---------". Could anybody help me? Thanks.

UPDATE:
Thanks guys, just found that it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739260/customize-remove-django-select-box-blank-option).

Looks like I will have to override either the **field** or **method** of the ModelForm.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to set `empty_label` to `None` for this.

```
type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=Item.TYPE_CHOICES, empty_label=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's for standard Form right? I don't have problem if I use the standard Form. But how can I disable that option in ModelForm? I mean I'd like to have only 2 options, "type 1" and "type 2", instead of "---------", "type 1" and "type 2", if I use ModelForm.

Comment: You could at least try my solution. Works just fine for me :P

Comment: It's directly overriding (re-defining) the field itself, which is not the solution I wanted for ModelForm. By doing this I even don't need "empty_label" argument to remove the empty option. The problem is that if "type" changes in Model later, I will then need to update the field in Form manually as well, which doesn't make sense for using ModelForm instead of regular Form. You are right it works well, but it's just not the best solution for ModelForm. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modelForm, you should overwrite the field in your form with `forms.ModelChoiceField()` instead of `models.ChoiceField()` then add the parameters as shown above replacing choices with queryset.

```
type = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), empty_label=None, queryset=TYPE.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way, without overriding anything: just add `default=1` like so:

```
type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=1)
```

Found this in Django source:

```
           include_blank = (self.blank or
                         not (self.has_default() or 'initial' in kwargs))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's arriving here from Google for a suitable answer for modern versions of Django and that have a `models.py` and `admin.py` setup similar to below.

```py
# models.py

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    SAMPLE_OPTIONS = (
        ('Option 1', 'Option 1'),
        ('Option 2', 'Option 2'),
    )
    ...
    sample_options = models.CharField(
        _('Sample Options'),
        choices=SAMPLE_OPTIONS,
        default='Option 1',
        blank=False,
        max_length=17,
    )
    ...

# admin.py

class SampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    radio_fields = {'sample_options': admin.HORIZONTAL}
    ...
```

If the `blank` argument is set to `True`, there will be 3 options:

1. None
2. Option 1
3. Option 2

If the `blank` argument is set to `False`, there will just be the two options:

1. Option 1
2. Option 2

Answer (score -2):

As I see It's a duplicate of [how-to-get-rid-of-the-bogus-choice-generated-by-radioselect-of-django-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824037/how-to-get-rid-of-the-bogus-choice-generated-by-radioselect-of-django-form)

the answer is there, and additional links, hope will help.

**EDIT**

so maybe if you try this, (i didn't do it, no warranty :) )

```
widget = {
            'type': forms.RadioSelect(choices=Item.TYPE_CHOICES),
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't work for ModelForm. I found something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739260/customize-remove-django-select-box-blank-option).